# Angular 10 + CKEdtior5 + Alignment

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

Im trying to make this editor works.

I've installed the three basic editor module from NPM

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^4.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^34.2.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^34.2.0",
```

The basic editor works well but I cant find a way to make Alignment module works.
This is my configuration:

```
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';

 var editorConfig: Object = {
      toolbar: {
        items: [
          'heading',
          '|',
          'bold','italic','link',
          'bulletedList',
          'numberedList',
          '|',
          'alignment:left', 'alignment:right', 'alignment:center', 'alignment:justify',
          'imageUpload',
          'blockQuote',
          'undo',
          'redo'
        ]
      },
      plugins : [ Alignment ]
    };
```

When I add Alignment plugin, compile broke with an infinite errors likes:

```
./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/align-bottom.svg:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
```